# How to print out list one single time after append?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

```
list = ('S', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'C', 'S', 'R')
list1 = []
for i in list:
    if i == 'C':
        list1.append('C')
        print(list1)
```

So I was trying to create a empty list and add only `'C'` into list1. And calculate how many `'C'` are in the list1. Iteration of over the list and `len(list1)` but that would give me all the `len` of my iteration... what are easier ways of calculating numbers of only`'C'` in list1? without iteration?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take `print(list1)` out of the loop, do it after.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the built-in method `count()`.

Comment: As an aside, that is a *tuple* not a list... in any case, the simplest way is to use the built-in method `list.count("C")`. Of course, this uses iteration, but you cannot count the number of things in a list *without* iteration

Comment: Also note, your list there is actually of type `tuple`

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: The title doesn't really match your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to solve this:

##### classical loop

```
my_list = ('S', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'C', 'S', 'R')

i = 0
for letter in my_list:
    if letter == 'C':
        i+=1
print(i)
```

##### list comprehension

```
>>> len([None for i in my_list if i == 'C'])
8
```

##### filter

*NB. this might be most useful to count not strictly identical objects*

```
>>> len(list(filter('C'.__eq__, my_list)))
8
```

##### collections.Counter

(already proposed by @eduardosufan)

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(my_list)['C']
```

output: `8`

##### `list.count` method

```
>>> my_list.count('C')
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use collections counter https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter to count the number of "C" without iteration:

```
 from collections import Counter
 list = ('S', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'C', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'C', 'C', 'S', 'R')
 c = Counter(list)
 print(c)
print(c["C"])
```

Result:

```
Counter({'C': 8, 'S': 7, 'R': 6})
8
```

Answer (score 1):

so if your just looking to count how many "c" 's there are you could just edit your code to:

```
for i in list:
    if i == 'C':
        list1.append('C')
        x = x + 1 
print(x)
```